# Date value goes out of date constraints in Safari Mobile

Tags: ios, date, datepicker, mobile-safari

I am trying to understand the level of support of `<input type="date">` in iOS. I tested it with an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.0.3, even if I specify a `min` attribute the date picker lets me choose a date before the constraint.

The HTML code is this:

```
<input type="date" id="checkIn" name="checkIn" class="form-control input-sm" value="2014-05-26" min="2014-05-26" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-date-minDate="2014-05-26" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

The data attributes are set for this [datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) but I detect the field support via [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) so I'm really sure it does not interfere in any case with the datepicker.

So the question is: did I do something wrong or is the date field lacking constraints support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been having the same issue. It looks like although using `<input type="date">` does render a date field. The min attribute is not working.
This [website](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) clearly states that there is support lacking.

From the website,
**Partial support in iOS refers to a lack of support for attributes like step, min, or max.** You have not done anything wrong.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Seems like they ignore support of attributes so far! And don't support type date on desktop safari at all. Indeed, safari is new ie.